# How to access mouse event coordinates? (conveniently)

Tags: mouse, events

When getting events from `(read-event)` it's possible to access only  mouse events using `(mouse-movement-p event)`.

Inspecting the events I've found I can get the Y pixel location using `(cdr (nth 2 (nth 1 event))` however this seems overly cryptic.

What is a good way to access data in mouse motion events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of functions with the `posn` prefix to extract that information and more from mouse events.  One caveat is that many of them require a start/end event:

```
(let ((e (read-event)))
  (when (mouse-event-p e)
    (let ((x-y (posn-x-y (event-start e))))
      (message "Mouse event at: %d|%d" (car x-y) (cdr x-y)))))
```

Comment: How to access pixel coordinates?

Comment: Wasamasa answered exactly the question in your comment, no? `C-h f posn-x-y`.